# List of users by number of badges?

Tags: support, badges, statistics, data-explorer

- Where can I find a ranking of all mathSE users by total number of badges?
- Where can I find a ranking of all mathSE users by total number of gold badges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/535637/top-200-mathse-users-by-number-of-badges) is a query that gives the top 200 users ranked by number of badges.

Additionally, [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/537069/top-50-badge-earners-of-each-class) is a query that gives the top 50 users by each of:

- number of gold badges,
- number of silver badges, and
- number of bronze badges.